# Paypal: Can you use the api to request for a new IPN?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Sometimes it happens that my server can't receive the ipn (various reasons) and I wonder if there is a way to ask for it again. 
I know you can use the ipn tool from your paypal account to resend but I have hundreds of transaction every day and it will be very annoying to do this manually.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IPN fails then PayPal's system will automatically resend it again until it gets a good response back.  It'll typically wait something like 1 min, then 2 min, then 4, etc. and keep resending until it gets a 200 OK response back from your script, so this should be happening for you already.

If you end up with enough failures PayPal will eventually send you warnings and then if it still continues after that they'll disable your IPN so it doesn't waste their resources sending data to it.